# Saving an Object with NSKeyedArchiver with a key

Tags: swift, nskeyedarchiver

I have a load method as follow to read an object from a Stream:

```
load() -> MYOBJECTCLASS{          
      let data:NSData? = getBlob();      
      var mykeyedunarchiver:NSKeyedUnarchiver=NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: data!);
      mykeyedunarchiver.delegate = self;
      let temp=mykeyedunarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("rootobject")
                    if temp==nil {
                        blobsexists=false;
                    }else{
                        objectreturn = temp! as! MYOBJECTCLASS;
                        return objectreturn;
                    }
}
```

What is the correlating save() method ?

I tried the following:

```
save1(myobject:MYOBJECTCLASS){
        let data = NSMutableData()
        var keyedarchiver:NSKeyedArchiver=NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData: data);
        keyedarchiver.encodeObject(maptheme, forKey: "rootobject");
        let bytes = data.bytes;
        let len=data.length; // len=0 !!!!!!!;
        saveblob(bytes);
}
```

len is 0 , so it did not work.

```
save2(myobject:MYOBJECTCLASS){
        var keyedarchiver:NSKeyedArchiver=NSKeyedArchiver();
        //let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(MYOBJECTCLASS_INSTANCE) // This works, but I need to save with a key.
        let data : NSData = keyedarchiver.encodeObject(myobject, forKey: "rootobject")
        let bytes = data.bytes;
        saveblob(bytes);
}
```

I get a "Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to type NSData.

getblob() and saveblob() are my own blob handling methods, which are working fine.

**Solution found**
I need to add

```
keyedarchiver.finishEncoding(); // insert the line after keyedarchiver.encodeObject(maptheme, forKey: "rootobject");
```

in my save1 and it works.

Comment: `encodeObject:forKey:` has no return value. Please read the chapters `Creating and Extracting Archives` and `Encoding and Decoding Objects` of https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html to understand the difference between `archiving` and `en/decoding`

Comment: I know this, because I get this Error. I just wanted to show my misunderstanding. Meanwhile I found the solution for the problem luckely. I need to just add the keyedarchiver.finishEncoding(); in my save1() and then it works.